# Should I use sparse index for boolean flags in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongoid

I have a boolean flag `:finished`. Should I

```
A: index({ finished: 1 })
B: index({ finished: 1 }, {sparse: true})
C: use flag :unfinished instead, to query by that
D: other?
```

Ruby mongoid syntax. Most my records will have flag finished=true, and most operations fetch those unfinished, obviously. I'm not sure if I understand when to use sparse and when not to. Thanks!

Comment: Use unfinished flag and create sparse index on that flag.

Comment: Reason: the fewer results you get with your index / the more specific your index is, the higher will be your performance gain.

Comment: Further to xeraa's point, Mongo specifically call out [selectivity](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-queries-that-ensure-selectivity/) in their docs. (It also applies to other DB platforms.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The sparse flag is a little weird. To understand when to use it, you have to understand why "sparse" exists in the first place.

When you create a simple index on one field, there is an entry for each document, even documents that don't have that field.

For example, if you have an index on `{rarely_set_field : 1}`, you will have an index that is filled mostly with `null` because that field doesn't exist in most cases. This is a waste of space and it's inefficient to search.

The `{sparse:true}` option will get rid of the `null` values, so you get an index that only contain entries when `{rarely_set_field}` is defined.

**Back to your case.**

You are asking about using a boolean + sparse. But sparse doesn't really affect "boolean", sparse affect "is set vs. is not set".

In your case, you are trying to fetch `unfinished`. To leverage `sparse` the key is not the boolean value, but the fact that `unfinished` entries have that key and that "finished" entries have no key at all.

```
{ _id: 1, data: {...}, unfinished: true }
{ _id: 2, data: {...} } // this entry is finished
```

**It sounds like you are using a Queue**

You can definitely leverage the information above to implement a sparse index. However, it actually sounds like you are using a Queue. MongoDB is serviceable as a Queue, here are [two](http://blog.serverdensity.com/2011/09/28/replacing-rabbitmq-with-mongodb/) [examples](http://captaincodeman.com/2011/05/28/simple-service-bus-message-queue-mongodb/).

However, if you look at the Queue, they are not doing it the way you are doing it. I'm personally using MongoDB as a Queue for some production systems and it runs pretty well, but test your expected load as a dedicated Queue will perform much better.

Comment: what's the drawback of using sparse?

Comment: The index only contains entries where the field is defined. So the drawback is that you can't use sparse with multiple fields and it can provide incomplete results when combined with other fields.

Comment: @GatesVP, if interested in an `exact` match, sparse would be suitable? Example: compound-index on `name` and `age`. If I only wanted to find `name=Kevin` and `age=100`, then `sparse` would be appropriate since it would exclude documents without `name` AND `age`, right?

Answer (score 2):

Sparse is only helpful if the value is `null`, not `false`. When you say "most will have finished=true", I'm guessing that most of `finished` is non-`null`, making sparse not very beneficial.

And since most values are a single value, I doubt any type of index would help at all if your queries are specific enough.

Comment: `true` or not present (`null` as you say) was the plan.