# Indexing Boolean values in NoSQL?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database, nosql

We are using MongoDB for our storage.
We have a collection like the folowing.

```
collection{
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("....."),
    "dataCriacao" : ISODate("..."),
    "ativo" : true,
    "title" : "tile",
    "text" : "text",
    "badge" : 0,
    "pedidoId" : null,
    "userID" : null,
    "createdByAdmin" : true
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "dataCriacao" : ISODate("..."),
    "ativo" : true,
    "title" : null,
    "text" : null,
    "badge" : 0,
    "pedidoId" : "2",
    "userID" : "6098821",
    "createdByAdmin" : false
}}
```

The collection is expected to get quite big and i will often query it depending on createdByAdmin. In this situation is it worth it to add an index on this field? My boss told me to but everything I found online is against indexes on boolean fields.

Comment: Please state where you found that information and what arguments were presented there.

Comment: I was mostly going by this post, though it doesn't differentiate between SQl and noSQL http://stackoverflow.com/a/1130/3362717

Comment: You might consider there are 3 states: true, false, and unset. Indexing the field, with sparse, could make good sense. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121403/should-i-use-sparse-index-for-boolean-flags-in-mongodb

Comment: Can you share an example of a standard query as well? You will want to create queries that can be as selective as possible in which documents it has to look at. Your indexes should then be built to support. More on selectivity here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-queries-that-ensure-selectivity/

Comment: my queries are just findAll where createdByAdmin==false, and findAll where createdByAdmin==true. the way my program runs createdByAdmin will never be unset, just true/false